# What MUI DataGrid methods will trigger before the onStateChange?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

For example:
This method gets triggered on any state change:

```
<DataGrid>
  onStateChange={function (params, evt, details) {

});
</DataGrid>
```

All of these methods will trigger before the above onStateChange method.

- onFilterModelChange
- onSortModelChange
- onColumnVisibilityModelChange
- onPinnedColumnsChange

What else will trigger before the onStateChange method?

Comment: Duplicate of asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704176/how-to-know-when-the-onstatechange-on-mui-data-grid-is-not-during-a-loading-stat/77241792?noredirect=1#comment136174383_77241792

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know when the onStateChange on Mui data grid is NOT during a loading state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704176/how-to-know-when-the-onstatechange-on-mui-data-grid-is-not-during-a-loading-stat)