# How to know when the onStateChange on Mui data grid is NOT during a loading state?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

The method onStateChange in mui data grid gets triggered whenever the state changes.
This happens like 6+ times during loading of the page.

So I've put int a temporary solution:
ie

```
<DataGrid
        onFilterModelChange={(model, details: any) => {
          refLoaded.current = true;
          updatedProps.onFilterModelChange?.(model, details);
        }}
        onSortModelChange={(model, details) => {
          refLoaded.current = true;
          updatedProps.onSortModelChange?.(model, details);
        }}
        onColumnVisibilityModelChange={(model, details) => {
          refLoaded.current = true;
          updatedProps.onColumnVisibilityModelChange?.(model, details);
        }} />
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function stops onStateChange to call continuously for DataGrid .
Can have function on comparing filterCount or sortModel :

```
onStateChange={(e) => {
                  if (JSON.stringify(this.state.filteredCountFAGrid) !== JSON.stringify(e.pagination.rowCount)){
                    console.log("new sort", e.pagination.rowCount);
                    this.setState({
                      filteredCountFAGrid: e.pagination.rowCount
                    });
                  }
                }}
```

Comment: That's an expensive solution using JSON.stringify.

Comment: we can remove  JSON.stringify to normal as this a number check

Comment: @Sandeeo Jain - apologies for delay. What has pagination.rowCount got to do with determining if its the first loading state?